# Splitted bar chart for paired data with highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to create charts like this with highcharts out of box?

[image]

Comment: Yes. Is there a particular problem you are having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set multiple y axes, and position them next to each other.

Example Code:

```
yAxis: [{  
    left: 120, width: 200,
},{
    offset: 0,
    left: 345, width: 200,
}]
```

Make sure to assign your series to the appropriate axis, for example:

```
series: [{
  yAxis: 0,
  name: 'Series 1'
  data: [...]
},{
  yAxis: 1,
  name: 'Series 2'
  data: [...]
]}
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/rgby8sqg/

Comment: Is there a way to get the yAsix to the centre? between the two bar charts.

Comment: Sure, just use the `offset` property of the `xAxis`. **Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/rgby8sqg/2/ **Reference**: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.offset